# Cannot pass Instance Ids into an automation association

Tags: automation, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm, amazon-systems-manager

Is there a way to run Automation SSM Documents using Terraform?

Typically, when invoking a document such as **AWS-StopEC2Instance**, the target is specified as an EC2 instance, aligning with the document's purpose of stopping an EC2 instance.

However, in my case, I'm calling the **AWS-CreateDSManagementInstance** automation document which creates an AWS Directory Service Windows Management instance.

**Sample Terraform config.**

```
data "aws_ssm_document" "directory_management" {
    name            = "AWS-CreateDSManagementInstance"
    document_format = "YAML"
  }
```

```
resource "aws_ssm_association" "domain_service_management_instance" {
  name = data.aws_ssm_document.directory_management.name

  automation_target_parameter_name = "InstanceId"

  parameters = {
    DirectoryId            = aws_directory_service_directory.aws-managed-ad[0].id
    KeyPairName            = var.key_name
    IamInstanceProfileName = aws_iam_instance_profile.controller.name
    SecurityGroupName      = aws_security_group.amazon_ssm_directory_service_security_group.id
    AmiId                  = var.directory_management_ami_id
    InstanceType           = var.windows_instance_type
    AutomationAssumeRole   = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/aws-service-role/ssm.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonSSM"
  }

  targets {
    key    = "InstanceIds"
    values = [aws_instance.directory_service_mgt_instance[0].id]
  }
}
```

But I get the error
`Error: creating SSM association: InvalidTarget: Cannot pass Instance Ids into an automation association`

How can I use Terraform to simply execute an automation document while passing in the required parameters?

Comment: Can you do that manually in the AWS console?

Comment: @Helder Sepulveda
I can, but I was hoping to automate it if possible.

Comment: The idea to create it manually is so later you can use genarate-config-out that way you see what is the difference  https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import/generating-configuration